# Does wikipedia state the definition of probability correctly?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In the wikipedia article on probability http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability it says:

> To qualify as a probability, the assignment of values must satisfy the
>   requirement that if you look at a collection of mutually exclusive
>   events (events with no common results, e.g., the events {1,6}, {3},
>   and {2,4} are all mutually exclusive), the probability that at least
>   one of the events will occur is given by the sum of the probabilities
>   of all the individual events

That 'at least one' troubles me. If the events are mutually exclusive, how could the number ever be greater than one? Should it not better read "exactly one"?

Comment: It doesn't say the *probability* is "at least one." It says the probability *of* at least one event is the *sum* of the probabilities of the individual events.

Comment: Thanks. Yep, what I'm not understanding is why it says the probability of at least one event, when it has just stated that the events are mutually exclusive. I would have thought (I'm just starting out in probability) that if events are mutually exclusive, then only one of them can occur. To say 'at least one' implies that under certain circumstances more than one of the events might occur. Wanted to check my understanding.

Comment: All it's saying is that when you roll a die, the probability of ("roll a 1" *or* "roll a 2" *or* both) is just the probability of "roll a 1" *plus* the probability of "roll a 2" -- *because* there is no way for *both* to happen (they are mutually exclusive).

Comment: If they're mutually exclusive, then at least one occurs if and only if exactly one occurs.  That doesn't mean it's logically wrong to say "at least one".  I might have said "the probability that one of the events occurs". ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

Due to their disjointness, the two statements are equivalent. It's not wrong what wikipedia states here, it actually is "nicer" in a way because the mathematical notation for it is simpler.
$$\Pr\Big(\bigcup_{k=1}^N A_k \Big) = \sum_{k=1}^N \Pr(A_k) \qquad \forall (A_k)_{k=1}^N, A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset \ \forall i\ne j$$

This coincides with additivity of a measure $\Pr$.